# Pandas GroupBy, to compare the new column of list of numbers, to another column of list of numbers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

A data frame is as the left of screenshot below.

I want to GroupBy the names, and find out which numbers (compared to [1,2,3,4,5]) are missing.

The ideal output is as the right of screenshot.

I've tried below codes. But the column 'Number of stars' after the GroupBy, is being taken as a list of strings. So it doesn't perform the comparison.

How can I fix it?

[image]

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

csvfile = StringIO("""
Name    Number of stars
Benjamin    1,3,2,1,2
Benjamin    2,5,1,3
Emma    2,1,1,4,4,2
Ethan   2,5,4
Emma    2,2,2
Ethan   5,4,4,1,1,1
Olivia  4,1,3,5""")

df = pd.read_csv(csvfile, sep = '\t', engine='python')

df_1 = df.groupby('Name')['Number of stars'].apply(list)

df_1 = df_1.to_frame().reset_index()

df_1['all stars'] = pd.Series([list(range(1,6)) for x in range(len(df_1.index))])
df_1['diff'] = df_1['all stars'].map(set) - df_1['Number of stars'].map(set)

print (df_1)
```

Output:

```
   Name       Number of stars        all stars             diff
0  Benjamin  [1,3,2,1,2, 2,5,1,3]  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]  {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
1      Emma  [2,1,1,4,4,2, 2,2,2]  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]  {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
2     Ethan  [2,5,4, 5,4,4,1,1,1]  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]  {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
3    Olivia             [4,1,3,5]  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]  {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us group the dataframe by `Name` and aggregate `Number of stars` with custom lambda function that returns the required set difference:

```
s = set(range(1, 6))
df.groupby('Name')['Number of stars']\
  .agg(lambda x: s - set(int(z) for y in x for z in y.split(',')))
```

---

```
Name
Benjamin       {4}
Emma        {3, 5}
Ethan          {3}
Olivia         {2}
Name: Number of stars, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```py
out = (
    df.groupby("Name")["Number of stars"]
    .apply(
        lambda x: ",".join(set("12345").difference(x.str.split(",").explode()))
    )
    .reset_index(name="diff")
)
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
       Name diff
0  Benjamin    4
1      Emma  3,5
2     Ethan    3
3    Olivia    2
```

Comment: thank you! May I have your understanding that I chose another one as the answer, which is a little flexible?

Answer (score 1):

You can convert comma separated string to list of string   then explode and groupby to get set

```py
df['Number of stars'] = df['Number of stars'].str.split(',')
df = df.explode('Number of stars')
df['Number of stars'] = df['Number of stars'].astype(int)

df_1 = (df.groupby('Name')['Number of stars'].apply(set)
        .to_frame().reset_index())
df_1['diff'] = df_1['Number of stars'].apply(lambda x: set(range(1,6))-x)
```

```
print(df_1)

       Name Number of stars    diff
0  Benjamin    {1, 2, 3, 5}     {4}
1      Emma       {1, 2, 4}  {3, 5}
2     Ethan    {1, 2, 4, 5}     {3}
3    Olivia    {1, 3, 4, 5}     {2}
```

Comment: thank you! your answer is very helpful in understand the working logic. however, hope you don't mind I chose another one for answer.